# BigQuery - why do i have to group by all columns?

Tags: google-bigquery

The error message for the following query:

```
SELECT
  sample_id,
  IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3930069__TGT", 1, 0) AS chr3_3930069__TGT,
  IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3929921_TC", 1, 0) AS chr3_3929921_TC,
  IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3929739_TC", 1, 0) AS chr3_3929739_TC,
  IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3929813__T", 1, 0) AS chr3_3929813__T,
  IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3929897_GA", 1, 0) AS chr3_3929897_GA,
  IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3929843_TC", 1, 0) AS chr3_3929843_TC
FROM
  [pgp_PIK3CA_all_distinct_features_values]
GROUP BY
  sample_id
```

is:

> Error: (L3:58): Expression 'chr3_3930069__TGT' is not present in the
>   GROUP BY list

How can i group by sample ID only, so i have a unique sample id at the rows and PIK3CA features at the columns?

Comment: Are you trying to get a count for each expression for `sample_id`? Can you edit your post and add what the expected output should be?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have aggregation function there to group all your columns by sample_id. You can add max to it, that should solve the issue.

```
SELECT
  sample_id,
  MAX(IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3930069__TGT", 1, 0)) AS chr3_3930069__TGT,
  MAX(IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3929921_TC", 1, 0)) AS chr3_3929921_TC,
  MAX(IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3929739_TC", 1, 0)) AS chr3_3929739_TC,
  MAX(IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3929813__T", 1, 0)) AS chr3_3929813__T,
  MAX(IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3929897_GA", 1, 0)) AS chr3_3929897_GA,
  MAX(IF(PIK3CA_features = "chr3_3929843_TC", 1, 0)) AS chr3_3929843_TC
FROM
  [pgp_PIK3CA_all_distinct_features_values]
GROUP BY
  sample_id
```